# GoogleUtilities.framework: errSecInternalComponent

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I just updated cocoa pods on my app and since then I am receiving errors. I can build and run in the simulator but not on a physical device. I was having trouble with the signing certificate because my keychain was saying it wasn't trusted. I revoked the certificate and  I changed the trust settings to always allow and that removed the red x from keychain and allowed the signing in on Xcode(now I have the blue cross on my developer certificate and not the green check). I have reintegrated and re installed all cocoa pods and cleaned out my derived data folder and this is still happening!  I don't know what else to do any suggestions would be appreciated.   my Xcode is version 11.4

this is my err log output

PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/disk87/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-glpfoebmdqlghdasamcnvwlyxnri/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Journal.build/Debug-iphoneos/Journal.build/Script-973FD177537A6DB4F8B46865.sh (in target 'Journal' from project 'Journal')
cd /Users/disk87/Desktop/App\ Store\ Apps/174\ Journal
/bin/sh -c /Users/disk87/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-glpfoebmdqlghdasamcnvwlyxnri/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Journal.build/Debug-iphoneos/Journal.build/Script-973FD177537A6DB4F8B46865.sh

mkdir -p /Users/disk87/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-glpfoebmdqlghdasamcnvwlyxnri/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Journal.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/disk87/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-glpfoebmdqlghdasamcnvwlyxnri/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework" "/Users/disk87/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-

```
glpfoebmdqlghdasamcnvwlyxnri/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Journal.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
GoogleUtilities.framework/
GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
GoogleUtilities.framework/Info.plist

sent 343048 bytes  received 70 bytes  686236.00 bytes/sec
total size is 342757  speedup is 1.00
Code Signing /Users/disk87/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-glpfoebmdqlghdasamcnvwlyxnri/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Journal.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework with Identity Apple Development: Donald Schmidt (xxxxxxxxxx)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign AA16BEA367F182468DE702FB4FF873015FCF2275  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/disk87/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-glpfoebmdqlghdasamcnvwlyxnri/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Journal.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework'
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: Donald Schmidt (69RSNJ9CN7)"
/Users/disk87/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-glpfoebmdqlghdasamcnvwlyxnri/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Journal.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Co
```

mmand PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Answer (score 2):

ok after some digging it was Google Mobile Ads SDK if you don't have version after 7.64 it doesn't do the WWDR signing also after upgrading all pods I was getting iOS 8 Deployment target errors so I had to deintegrate pods reinstall earlier versions that included any  updates needed to work as follows

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~>7.65.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~>4.2.0'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```